# Power Point is not being converted to PDF using Microsoft Graph API calls

Tags: pdf, microsoft-graph-api, powerpoint, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

I am using Microsoft Graph calls to convert my presentation into pdf. Usually it converts successfully for general presentations but it fails if size of my ppt is little big(around 1 MB) or contains some high quality graphic images. I'm getting this response:

```
{
"error":{
      "code": "notSupported",
      "message": "Error from Office Service. Url=https://pptcs.officeapps.live.com/document/export/pdf HttpCode=BadRequest cert=subject:;thumbprint: ResponseHeaders=X-ErrorCode: PPTCannotPrint\r\nX-ErrorCategory: BadRequest\r\nX-IsRetriable: False\r\nX-FileDownloadTimeInMs: 718.7589\r\nX-ClientCorrelationId: 8bec156c-9d05-4422-a35f-d85f26189bfb\r\nX-ServiceCorrelationId: 8bec156c-9d05-4422-a35f-d85f26189bfb\r\nX-ConversionTimeInMs: 140.6285\r\nCache-Control: private\r\nDate: Sat, 12 Sep 2020 18:28:17 GMT\r\nServer: Microsoft-IIS/10.0\r\nX-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319\r\nX-Powered-By: ASP.NET\r\n",
      "innererror": {
        "code": "invalidFileFormat"
      }
    }
}
```

Is it a known problem, also Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Please make sure the input file you're using is in .pptx format, as the error is telling it's invalid file format.

Comment: File is in .pptx format only, the only difference is file size is large(around 1MB)(because ppt file contains high quality graphic images.)

Comment: aah, that might be the problem. Instead of high quality try to see if you can reduce the medium or minimal one to see if it helps to move forward. This will help you to isolate the issue further and act as an workaround for you.